# Cannot execute commands as root following upgrade

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I accepted the invitation to upgrade my Lubuntu 20.04.6 LTS machine today, and have been unable to execute commands as root ever since - for example, if I try:

`sudo docker stop home-assistant`

I get:

`Sorry, user mhyuser is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/docker stop home-assistant' as root`

Any idea how I can fix this?? I'm a bit of a Linux noob....

Comment: See if `sudo grep "$USER" /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d/*` returns anything ... Also, please see what `sudo -l` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found the problem. I added my user to a new group a few days ago, and I'm guessing that, in doing so, I accidentally removed it from the sudo group. I have now logged in as root and re-added it to the sudo group, and the problem seems to be resolved.
Thanks for the feedback